# How to Upload Video to Pinterest via API

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, pinterest

I am trying to upload a video to Pinterest, so I followed the instructions in their docs [here](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/v5/#operation/media/create)

Here is how I attempted the upload

```
let headers = {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`
}
let videoUploadIntentEndpoint = `https://api.pinterest.com/v5/media`;
let videoUploadIntentResponse = await axios.post(videoUploadIntentEndpoint,
    {
        "media_type": "video"
    },
    {
        headers: headers
    }
);
let { media_id, upload_parameters, media_type, upload_url } = videoUploadIntentResponse.data;
if (media_id && upload_url) {
    try {
        let vidUploadParams = new URLSearchParams();
        vidUploadParams.append("file", got.stream(mediaUrl));
        let videoUploadResponse = await axios.post(upload_url, vidUploadParams, {
            headers: { ...upload_parameters }
        });
        let vidData = videoUploadResponse.data;
        console.log(`Pinterest Video Successful with Data`);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(vidData, null, 2));
    } catch (vidError) {
        console.log(`Pinterest Video Upload Error`);
        console.log(vidError);
    }
}
```

And the error I keep getting back is

> `AccessDenied`No AWSAccessKey was
> presented.AFHHW0M2afafafR9N8afafafafafafa+g5y3qsXqKwta0eN6ND03J7UDEjpk4F1/qbFrfec=

How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: show us your headers

Comment: @ManosKounelakis Question updated with headers. Thank you

Comment: I am facing the same issue now. It is really frustrating! Anyone with solution here?

Answer (score 0):

The doc isn't super clear, but the *upload_parameters* must be sent along the file in the **body**, not in the **headers**.
*"Send the media file's contents as the request's file parameter and also include all of the parameters from upload_parameters"* (this is confusing because *Content-Type* still belongs in the headers)

(the *AWSAccessKey* the error is talking about is the first part of the *x-amz-credentials* string)